# Touch ID doesn't work after several tries

Tags: iphone

So I've tried with most of my fingers, and both my thumbs. It doesn't work for me. (hopefully yet)

Most video tutorials/demo online just repeatedly tap the home button, and the red fills up the fingerprint onscreen. They tap when the phone vibrates while my doesn't vibrate and simply tells me to lift and then place again.

I don't see what I'm doing wrong, here's a video of my action, if someone can spot what I did wrong, please post it as an answer.

It's quite frustrating really.

Link to video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F3VM4RcQu1A

Answer (score 1):

Put your finger in different positions on the sensor.
[This](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8VtDDqXhydQ) video seems to explain it very well.

Also take a look at [Apple's documentation](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5883).

Comment: I will take a look, the Touch ID isn't really that well-documented on Apple's KB.

Comment: Well, I find it very well actually. Take a look at the second link. There is a section called "Troubleshooting".

Comment: I did look at that. It seems you have a 5s, my phone doesn't vibrate when I'm doing it, did yours?

Comment: On the video you provided, the red doesn't fade away when he's done scanning, mine does, I don't know why. Troubleshooting tells me to bring to a local apple store. LOL

Comment: May be your hardware is defect. So why not try to bring it to a local Apple Store?

Comment: Most likely. I'm gonna wait a few weeks or even months then. I live in Taiwan (a country in Asia) and we're out of stock, so the chance of getting it replaced now is quite small. Also, I will try with others hand then, maybe it's me. LOL Thanks for answering anyways!

Comment: Also, did yours vibrate during the process? (or make any sound?) All the video I see doesn't show "Lift you finger" like mine does.

Answer (score 1):

Try covering the button with your finger edge-to-edge. When prompted to "Lift your finger" lift your finger and place it on the button in a slightly different orientation with a slightly different part of your finger and a slightly different angle. Then do it again.

You want complete coverage of your finger on the button so that it will work with your finger in more than one orientation and placement.

Comment: The odd thing is it always stuck at the fourth try, it doesn't turn into "Lift your finger". Tried your method and changed the orientation between scans, doesn't work. Still stuck at the fourth scan.

Answer (score 0):

After trying for hours. I did give up. I brought it to school the next day and have my friend try it, he realize that there's protector on the home button which I didn't relize when the clerk is finishing up my phone.

Anyway, it's quite stupid, but definitely a thing check before bringing the phone in for repair.